# How to successfully reverse proxy react application with ngnix?

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a containerless node application that is running on port 8181. I'm attempting to add a Ngnix reverse proxy to a react front-end application that is deployed into a docker container by using a Dockerfile. I'm not using docker-compose, but I'm willing to if it is needed to get this up and running. The plan is to get this working locally and be able to deploy it to Google's app engine (F/E) and google cloud run (b/e) while simply updating the proxy_pass value with an environment variable. Locally, it's failing with a status of 502 bad gateway and I'm having a hard time seeing why. Any insight?  Hoping to have each request from localhost/api/* proxy_pass to localhost:8181/api/*.

My Backend Routes:

/app.js

```
app.use('/api', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/api/test', require('./routes/test.routes'));
```

/routes/index.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('loading the app');
});
```

Running on port 8181.

Frontend:

app-web/ngnix.conf

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location /api {
            resolver 127.0.0.11;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

app-web/Dockerfile

```
# stage1 as builder
FROM node:10-alpine as builder

# copy the package.json to install dependencies
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

# Install the dependencies and make the folder
RUN npm install && mkdir /app-web && mv ./node_modules ./app-web

WORKDIR /app-web

COPY . .

# Build the project and copy the files
RUN npm run build


FROM nginx:alpine

#!/bin/sh

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

## Remove default nginx index page
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Copy from the stahg 1
COPY --from=builder /app-web/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 8181 80

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The Request Endpoint that's receiving error:

```
HTTP://localhost/api/
```

Command to run after Build step.

```
docker run -d --name app-web -p 80:80  app-web
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u r using the expose command wrong. As far as i know it doesnt get 2nd argument only the first one which lets the user know which port he should publish. It is for informative use only, it doesnt actually publish the port. So maybe try

`docker run -d --name app-web -p 8180:80  app-web`

Comment: This did not work. -p  80:80 maps all requests from the container to the port on the host. It actually prevented the app from being served up.